# How to set 404 error response format to JSON in Hanami

Tags: rest, hanami

I'm writing REST API for application with Hanami ruby web framework, and I'm wondering how to set error format to JSON. For example,when 404 error occurred it should return response with body `{'message': 'Method not found'}, and Content-Type: 'application/json'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set format to json.

```
format: :json
```

See Mime Types [Documentation](http://hanamirb.org/guides/views/mime-types/)

Comment: Option `format` works with controllers, but according to this page you may just rename 404 error template to 404.json.rb,  and it works. Thank you

Comment: But where the `format: :json` should be placed? I also tried the solution with `404.json.slim` (I use Slim as a template engine) but it didn't help.

Comment: @AleksanderPohl You need to put this in your controller. There is no need for a template

Comment: But how about an invalid path that causes 404? This solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this while searching for something else, so thought I'd answer it even though it's a really old question.

One quick way to do this would be to add a catch-all route at the very end of your routes.
e.g.

```
# apps/web/config/routes.rb

get '/*', to: ->(env) { [404, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }, ["Method not found"]] }
```

Since you're using Hanami, the `http-router` configuration (where you could usually define a `default_app` option) isn't available to you directly.

See `lib/hanami/routing/default.rb` for the default "not found" action if you prefer to consider another approach with monkey-patching (or some way to supply a configuration option that I'm not aware of at this point).